# Can GridView be filled with var?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am trying to display duplicate rows between an excel sheet and a sql server datatable in a GridView.

This is me code:

```
var matched = (from table1 in dt4.AsEnumerable()
                join table2 in oltlb.AsEnumerable() on
                table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
                where table1.Field<string>("Data") == table2.Field<string>("Data")
                select table1);
DataTable dthi5 = new DataTable();
dthi5 = matched.CopyToDataTable();
```

can i display the values of var in a GridView?

Comment: try converting it to .ToList();

Comment: Please can you specify where i need to add .ToList()? I am a beginner.

Comment: try binding `dth15` to the GridView

Comment: Something is terribly wrong with your example!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be filled with your variable. (In this case you have to cast it `.ToList()`)

You have to understand that `var` is strongly typed! It is not like in php, where you can switch the type of a variable.

Try writing

```
var x = null;
```

in Visual Studio. There will be an error!

Your `var` **everytime** has to be declared type safe. It is just a short spell to make programmers don't allways have to write long typenames in front of their variables. So your `var` in your case is the an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Sorry i am a complete newbie can you explain where am i supposed to add or replace in above code?

Comment: Just add .ToList() - ...select table1).ToList();

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I added .ToList(); as you said  and then GridView1.DataSource=matched;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var matched = (from table1 in dt4.AsEnumerable()
                  join table2 in oltlb.AsEnumerable() on
                table1.Field<int>("ID") equals table2.Field<int>("ID")
                  where table1.Field<string>("Data") == table2.Field<string>("Data")
                  select table1);
      DataTable dthi5 = new DataTable();
      dthi5 = matched.CopyToDataTable();

myGridView.DataSource = dthi5;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Or

```
myGridView = matched.ToList();
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely bind var to gridview.

Let's assume there's an employee table with three fields

> emp_id    emp_fname    emp_lname

First way: if you give the whole table or a particular record to var then to list would work...

employees is a data context class once you've established a successful connection to sql server..

```
var result = from alias in dc.employees
          where alias.emp_id == id --(this is the passed parameter)
```

You can also manually specify the id, for example:

```
where alias.emp_id == 5
          select alias;
```

The whole employee record having id = 5 would get selected.

You can now simply bind this to gridview

```
gridview1.datasource = result.tolist();
gridview1.databind();
```

If you give the whole table, then also tolist would work

```
var result  = from alias in dc.employess
              select alias;

gridview1.datasource = result.tolist();
gridview1.databind();
```

If you select multiple columns then tolist won't work. You need to return object.

the method has been defined in class1.

```
public static object returnquery()
{

dcdatacontext dc = new dcdatacontext();

var result = from alias in dc.employees
             where alias.emp_id == 5
             select new
             {
                alias.emp_fname,
                alais.emp_lname
             };

 return result;
}
```

You need to catch the object.

```
object obj = new class1.returnquery();

gridview1.datasource = obj;
gridview1.databind();
```

Or you can simply try this and see if it works. I haven't tried this actually.

```
var result = from alias in dc.employees
             where alias.emp_id == 5
             select new
             {
                alias.emp_fname,
                alias.emp_lname
             };

gridview1.datasource= result.object();
gridview1.databind();
```